# Arduino function interfering with loop() code

Tags: arrays, arduino

I have, among others, the following lines in the loop function:

```
item = String(buffer);
Serial.println(item);
```

Where item is a String and buffer a char array. This works perfectly until I add a function at the end of the file (outside of the loop function):

```
void storeData(String item){
  Serial.println("StoreData");
  for (int k=0; k<11; k++){
    Serial.print("*");
    if(item == products[k]){
      items[index] = names[k];
      index++;
      Serial.print("\n");
      Serial.print(item);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(names[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Which compares the string `item` to a list of values and stores the corresponding name if the value is found. 
When I add this code at the end, even if I DON'T call on the function, the output of the conversion becomes:

```
978973103 Á
9789731030418
```

Where the first value is the incorrect conversion and the second one is the value of `buffer`.

What could possibly be happening? I've restarted and rewired and redone everything from scratch over and over again.

Comment: If there is no memory issue (running out of memory) are you certain that item = String(buffer) copies a null terminated array? A quick print right after assignment should clear up that. If item is correct, as others indicated, the MemoryFree library is nice to use, at least during development to keep an eye on the available memory.

Comment: The array contains no more than 14 characters (numbers). It is printed correctly (`9789731030418`) as opposed to the conversion which goes haywire `978973103 Á  `...

Comment: I had a weird problem at a time where I passed a char buffer to a function and the program state would go weird after a while. I removed the char buffer from the function call and used it as a global variable and all was fine. I also read that the String type had some allocation bugs in earlier versions, what version is your compiler?

Comment: Google search for string allocation bugs https://www.google.ca/search?q=arduino+string+allocation+bug&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible you are running out of the 2K SRAM. Arrays of Strings can quickly use it up.

Additionally I recommend using the `F()` function as not use use RAM for constanst. e.g. `Serial.println(F("StoreData")`;

The latest IDE's show the expected RAM usage. but this is a guess. If it is even close then there is likely an issue. I use the following [MemoryFree library](https://github.com/mpflaga/Arduino-MemoryFree) at specific points in the code to reveal the highwater.

Comment: I considered the RAM issue, but how can that be? A for with 12 iterations and an if that aren't even called?

Comment: It was, in fact the RAM. Found out by elimination that it's the GLCD I'm using. Only the library and inits take up 5k in the sketch. I can't even imagine how much it hogs the RAM. Thank you for taking your time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Since item is string. I think you can try using

```
Serial.println(item);
```

instead of

```
Serial.print(item);
```

in you storeData function. Also similarly for other strings